# Splitting string by the first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, split

I have a string in the next format

```
id;some text here with possible ; inside
```

and want to split it to 2 strings by first occurrence of the `;`. So, it should be: `id` and `some text here with possible ; inside`

I know how to split the string (for instance, with `cut -d ';' -f1`), but it will split to more parts since I have `;` inside the left part.

Comment: After the string is split what do you want to do with the "id"? Do you want to assign it to a variable, print it out, etc?

Comment: I gonna have 2 variables: `id` and `string`

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`cut` sounds like a suitable tool for this:

```
bash-4.2$ s='id;some text here with possible ; inside'

bash-4.2$ id="$( cut -d ';' -f 1 <<< "$s" )"; echo "$id"
id

bash-4.2$ string="$( cut -d ';' -f 2- <<< "$s" )"; echo "$string"
some text here with possible ; inside
```

But `read` is even more suitable:

```
bash-4.2$ IFS=';' read -r id string <<< "$s"

bash-4.2$ echo "$id"
id

bash-4.2$ echo "$string"
some text here with possible ; inside
```

Comment: Great! It works like a charm! I will select the `read` since i'm using `bash`. Thank you @manatwork!

Comment: The `cut` approach will only work when "$s" doesn't contain newline characters. read is in any Bourne-like shell. <<< is in rc, zsh and recent versions of bash and ksh93 and is the one that is not standard.

Comment: Oops, you are right @StephaneChazelas. My mind was at `-a` for some reason when mentioning `bash`'s `read`. (Evidently of no use here.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the read approach doesn't work if $s contains newline characters either. I've added my own answer.

Comment: I would like to emphasize the trailing dash in `-f 2-` in the `string="$( cut -d ';' -f 2- <<< "$s" )"; echo "$string"` command. This is what ignores the rest of the delimiters in the string for the printout. Not obvious when looking at the man page of `cut`

Comment: Even better, for the first example, is to set `string` equal to `"${s:$((${#id} + 1))}"`. This slices off the first string from the original string, plus a character for the `;`.

Comment: @distilledchaos, yes, that is also a way. I will keep the first example with `cut` as that is the question owner had problem with. Regarding your suggestion, note that parameter expansion's arguments are subject to arithmetic evaluation, so the explicit `$((…))` is not necessary: `string="${s:${#id} + 1}"`.

Comment: great! This works perfect for me. Thumbs up.

Comment: `read` is fine, as long as you're not inside a `while` loop.  Please, let's all of use learn [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Answer (score 27):

With any standard sh (including bash):

```
sep=';'
case $s in
  (*"$sep"*)
    before=${s%%"$sep"*}
    after=${s#*"$sep"}
    ;;
  (*)
    before=$s
    after=
    ;;
esac
```

`read` based solutions would work for single character (and with some shells, single-byte) values of `$sep` other than space, tab or newline and only if `$s` doesn't contain newline characters.

`cut` based solutions would only work if `$s` doesn't contain newline characters.

`sed` solutions could be devised that handle all the corner cases with any value of `$sep`, but it's not worth going that far when there's builtin support in the shell for that.

Answer (score 9):

Solution in standard bash:

```
    text='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
    text2=${text#*;}
    text1=${text%"$text2"}

    echo $text1
    #=> id;
    echo $text2
    #=> some text here with possible ; insideDD
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! Best answer. Although you need to do `text1=${text%";$text2"}` to remove the trailing `;` in `$1text`

Comment: @pez, but with that, for values of `$text` not containing `;`, you'll end up with both `$text1` and `$text2` containing `$text`. You'd need `text1=${text%%;*}; text2=${text#"$text1"}; text2=${text2#;}`, or handle it as a special case like in [my answer](/a/53323).

Answer (score 8):

As you have mentioned that you want to assign the values to **id** and **string**

first assign your pattern to a variable(say str)

```
    str='id;some text here with possible ; inside'
    id=${str%%;} 
    string=${str#;}
```

Now you have your values in respective variables

Comment: if you are getting your pattern from a command then use set --           `some_command` ,then your pattern will get stored in $1 and use the above code with 1 instead of str

Comment: How is this answer different from @StephaneChazelas?

Comment: Should be `${str%%;*}` for id and `${str#*;}` for `str` (with the asterisks). This is an old answer though so perhaps this worked on older versions of bash, but these changes were required for me on bash 4.2+ (and possibly earlier, I did not test).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other solutions, you could try something `regex` based:

```
a="$(sed 's/;.*//' <<< "$s")"
b="$(sed 's/^[^;]*;//' <<< "$s")"
```

or depending on what you are trying to do exactly, you could use

```
sed -r 's/^([^;]*);(.*)/\1 ADD THIS TEXT BETWEEN YOUR STRINGS \2/'
```

where `\1` and `\2` contain the two substrings you were wanting.