# Using cut/awk/sed with two different delimiters

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, cut

I have the following cases:

```
 case@test.com
 case_1_2@test.com
 case_1@test.com
```

I'm trying to convert these to

```
 case@test.com
 case@test.com
 case@test.com
```

So it should remove everything from the first '_' (including it) to the @ (not including that).

I have something, but it doesn't really work correctly:

Based on this thread: [Cut based on Two Delimiters at one go](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/34542-cut-based-two-delimiters-one-go.html), and this U&L Q&A: [Splitting string by the first occurrence of a delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/splitting-string-by-the-first-occurrence-of-a-delimiter).

```
sed 's/^.*_\([^ ]*\) .*\@\([^$]*\)$/\1 \2/' infile
```

But no luck. Anyone want to take a chime at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you won't ever have more than one `@` symbol,

```
sed 's/_.*@/@/' file.txt
```

...should work.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're really doing with this but your could do it like so with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(case\).*\(@test.com\)/\1\2/' 87529.txt 
case@test.com
case@test.com
case@test.com
```

This effectively trims everything out between `case` and the `@`.

You can do something similar with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F@ '{split($1,a,"_"); print a[1]"@"$2}' 87529.txt
```

Also can be done with `perl` (similar to evilsoup's approach):

```
$ perl -p -e 's/_.*@/@/g' 87529.txt
```

Or you can make use of [`perl`'s lookahead facility](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ perl -p -e 's/_.*(?=@)//g' 87529.txt
```

**NOTE:** Lookahead and lookbehind's in `perl` allow you to include strings in the regex pattern that you're matching on, without having them be included in the operation that will be performed against the regex. Think of them as dynamic versions of the caret (`^`) - beginning of a line, and dollar (`$`) - end of the line. This a little less hacky then having to add the `@` back in, after removing it.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports parameter expansion, you can do something like

```
while read line; do
    printf "%s\n" "${line%%_*}@${line#*@}"
done < your_file_here
```

The expansion `${line%%_*}` removes the leftmost `_` and everything following it while the expansion `${line#*@}` removes the leftmost `@` and everything preceding it.

Comment: As tagged [tag:bash], parameter expansion based solution can be shorter when used on array: http://pastebin.com/kgq89527

Comment: @manatwork Beautiful. I would say this merits to be in answer of its own with a short explanation perhaps...

Comment: However note that performance will be very poor on big files as anything using loops in bash, and that assumes all lines contain one @ and one _ before the left-most @ (and the other usual problems when using `read` with `-r` and without setting IFS)

Answer (score 1):

If the lines may contain more than one `@`:

```
sed 's/^\([^@_]*\)_[^@]*@/\1@/'
```

Or:

```
awk -F@ -vOFS=@ 'NF >= 2 {sub(/_.*/,"",$1)};1'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Evilsoup's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34494/evilsoup) [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87530/3879) seems to be perfect!

Yet another solution using both `sed` and `awk`.

```
sed 's/_/ /g; s/@/ /g' file_name | awk '{ print $1"@"$NF '}
```

This would not exactly count for efficiency, but may be simple to understand, perhaps, when one does not want to mess with regular expressions. The above code does the following:

- The first pattern of `sed` replaces "_" with a blank.
- The second pattern of `sed` replaces "@" with a blank. So, now we contents of the file separated into multiple columns:

> case test.com
>   case 1_2 test.com
>   case 1 test.com

- Finally, `awk` simply prints the first and last columns of the separated contents. Here, `NF` is a special symbol in `awk` that gives the number of fields in a row.

Comment: I think you need global substitutions (i.e. `s/_/ /g;`...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `gawk` way:

```
gawk -F_ '{if(NF>1){print $1$NF} else {print $NF}}'
```

Using `_` as a field delimiter, we tell `gawk` to print the first and last fields if there are more than one field and the last field if there is only a single field.