# Modify values in a column based on number of colons it contains

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut

I would manipulate the contents of the second column based on the number of colons it contains. If the second field contains more than one colon then I would require the content before first colon else I would require entire value.

```
#Input    
1 1131:11854476:4:1$ 0 114476 1 4
5 367504:11862778:4:2$ 0 118628 2 4
3 3:64357_3_2$ 0 18267 2 3 
4 7575:38680372:1$ 0 38372 1 2

# Output
1 1131 0 114476 1 4
5 367504 0 118628 2 4
3 3:64357_3_2$ 0 18267 2 3 
4 7575 0 386372 1 2
```

I have come across different suggestions to copy a single column after manipulating or processing entire file/[string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/splitting-string-by-the-first-occurrence-of-a-delimiter) but I would need to retain the remaining columns unprocessed. Could you please give ideas on how to achieve this in a single command (`awk`/`cut` one-liners) or multiple commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting string by the first occurrence of a delimiter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/splitting-string-by-the-first-occurrence-of-a-delimiter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `split` the 2nd field on `:` and if you get more than 2 pieces (that is, the number of elements in array `z`) keep only the 1st one:

```
awk '{n=split($2, z, ":");if (n > 2) $2=z[1]};1' infile
```

---

If you wanted to use `sub` you could do something like:

```
awk '{sub(/:.*:.*/,"",$2)};1' infile
```

that is, attempt to replace two colons (or more).

Comment: I was trying `awk '{sub(/:.*/,"",$2)}7'` but I was not able to keep 3 row from 2nd column which OP was asking. If I would wanted to modify my awk operation then what it would be ? and I would be thankful if you elaborate your one liner a bit more

Comment: @arzyfex - see my edit; is it still unclear ?